# NodeJS async/await order not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I'm new with **NodeJS** and **Promises**, so I might not been understanding how it works.

I'm loading a configuration file in my app, with the peculiarity that if it doesn't exist, I create it with the info from a call to database.

```
function getConfig(clientId, app) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    await fs.access(config.files.url_networks_file, async function(err) {
      if (err) {
        try {
          await loadClientConfig(clientId);
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      }
    });

    fs.readFile(config.files.url_networks_file, 'utf8', function(err, data) { // Try to read network's configuration file
      if (err) { // If file doesn't exists
        reject(err);
      } else if (JSON.parse(data)[app]) { // In case app's config exists
        resolve(JSON.parse(data)[app]);
      } else { // In case app's config doesn't exists
        reject(new Error('There\'s no configuration for app: ' + app));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

My problem is that `fs.readFile()` doesn't waits until `loadClientConfig()` finish, so it always return "file not found". If the config file already exists, it works perfectly.

I've tried putting `fs.readFile()` inside the `fs.access()` callback, still not getting anything (even if the file exists).

**UPDATE**

Still not working with the two solutions I received. I'm posting the code I made for each one to check if I lost something in the coding:

@Quentin

```
async function loadClientConfig(clientId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.access(config.files.url_networks_file, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                try {
                    sql.close();
                    sql.connect(config.database.credentials, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        } else {
                            var request = new sql.Request();
                            request.input('clientId', clientId);
                            query = config.database.queries.all;

                            request.query(query, function (e, data) {
                                if (e) {
                                    reject(e);
                                } else {
                                    try {
                                        resolve(writeConfigFile(data.recordset));
                                    } catch (err) {
                                        reject(err);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            }
        });
    });
};

async function getConfig(clientId, app) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      await loadClientConfig(clientId);
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }

    fs.readFile(config.files.url_networks_file, 'utf8', function(err, data) { // Try to read network's configuration file
      if (err) { // If file doesn't exists
        reject(err);
      } else if (JSON.parse(data)[app]) { // In case app's config exists
        resolve(JSON.parse(data)[app]);
      } else { // In case app's config doesn't exists
        reject(new Error('There\'s no configuration for app: ' + app));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

@dasfdsa

```
async function loadClientConfig(clientId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sql.close();
    sql.connect(config.database.credentials, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.input('clientId', clientId);
        query = config.database.queries.all;

        request.query(query, async function(e, data) {
          if (e) {
            reject(e);
          } else {              
            try {
              resolve(writeConfigFile(data.recordset));
            } catch (err) {
              reject(err);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
};

async function getConfig(clientId, app) {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.access(config.files.url_networks_file, async function (err) {
      if (err) {
        try {
          let temp = await loadClientConfig(clientId); /*Now that you told me its async, we will await it as well*/
          resolve(temp);
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
  let configuration = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(config.files.url_networks_file, 'utf8', function (err, data) { // Try to read network's configuration file
      if (err) { // If file doesn't exists
        reject(err);
      } else if (JSON.parse(data)[app]) { // In case app's config exists
        resolve(JSON.parse(data)[app]);
      } else { // In case app's config doesn't exists
        reject(new Error('There\'s no configuration for app: ' + app));
      }
    });
  });

  return configuration;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

It seems that works when debugging, I'm using VSCode. I think it may be a timeout issue or something similar.

Comment: The callback passed to `fs.access()` is tripping you up.

Comment: does `fs.access` return a promise (hint: no)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code: Two separate `awaited` `promise` for each callback. `getConfig` returns a `promise` which will resolve to `config`.

```
async function getConfig(clientId, app) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.access(config.files.url_networks_file, async function (err) {
            if (err) {
                try {
                    let temp = await loadClientConfig(clientId);/*Now that you told me its async, we will await it as well*/
                    resolve(temp);
                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            }
        });
    });
    let config = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(config.files.url_networks_file, 'utf8', function (err, data) { // Try to read network's configuration file
            if (err) { // If file doesn't exists
                reject(err);
            } else if (JSON.parse(data)[app]) { // In case app's config exists
                resolve(JSON.parse(data)[app]);
            } else { // In case app's config doesn't exists
                reject(new Error('There\'s no configuration for app: ' + app));
            }
        });
    });

    return config;

}
```

Edit: I have edited to await `loadClientConfig()`, above code should work fine if  `loadClientConfig` returns a promise.

Comment: Thanks for remark. I will remove it. If there is any error in `loadClientConfig(clientId)` it will go to next catch block and promise will be rejected.

Comment: Is `loadClientConfig` an async function?

Comment: Yes, it's an async function. I'm not getting any error, not even in console. I can update my answer with gaven solutions in case I coded something wrong.

Comment: Does it returns a promise? If yes, my now edited code will work fine.

Comment: I tried your solution with some minor modifications and finally get it working. Turns out that the problem was `nodemon`, I don't know why, but starting the server with `node` or even with de VS Code, works fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can only `await` a promise.

`fs.access` does not return a promise (it takes a callback instead). (It isn't possible to tell what `loadClientConfig` does as you didn't include that function in the question).

If you want to `await` it, then you'll need to wrap it in a function which does return a promise.

Comment: I've tried to move `fs.access`and still not working:

`await loadClientConfig(clientId);`
`fs.readFile(config.files.url_networks_file, 'utf8', function(err, data) { // Try to read network's configuration file`
`        if (err) { // If file doesn't exists`
`          reject(err);`
`        } else if (JSON.parse(data)[app]) { // In case app's config exists`
`          resolve(JSON.parse(data)[app]);`
`        } else { // In case app's config doesn't exists`
`          reject(new Error('There\'s no configuration for app: ' + app));`
`        }`
`      });`

Comment: @AndrésMarotta — I said you needed to wrap fs.access in a promise and you didn't.

Comment: `loadClientConfig` is a function that returns a promise, isn't that what you told me to do? I'm doing it with almost all my functions and works fine, always with a try-catch block.

Comment: @AndrésMarotta — You wanted `fs.readFile` to wait until `fs.access` was done. `fs.access` does not return a promise.

Comment: I'm going to post the solutions so it's easier to look at.